# HDFS replication factor - minimizing data loss risk

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, replication

**EDIT - TL;DR:**

Do *all* replica nodes have to store a file (all of its blocks) before a write to HDFS is considered successful? If so, does the replication factor affect the write latency?

**Original Question:**

In `Hadoop 2` I can control the number of data block replicas by setting the `dfs.replication` property to a value greater than 1 (The default is not always 3 in some hadoop distributions like EMR).

It's my understanding that HDFS behavior is to write the first replica synchronously while the others are pipelined and the replication happens in an asynchronous fashion. Is this correct?

If the above is true, then there is always a risk of data loss if the first node sends an ack to the namenode and then gets hit by a meteorite before being able to complete the asynchronous replication.

Is there a way to guarantee that at least a number X of nodes write the block before a write is considered successful? Would it be advisable to do so? I though that I could control this by using the `dfs.namenode.replication.min` property but I read that it's only used when in "safe mode" and thus cannot help during normal operations.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you see that the replication were not reliable?  From a Cloudera blog:

> When files are being written the data nodes form a pipeline to write
>   the replicas in sequence. Data is sent through the pipeline in packets
>   (smaller than a block), **each of which must be acknowledged to count as
>   a successful write.** If a data node fails while the block is being
>   written, it is removed from the pipeline. When the current block has
>   been written, thename node will re-replicate it to make up for the
>   missing replica due to the failed data node.Subsequent blocks will be
>   written using a new pipeline with the required number of datanodes

If replicated blocks were to fail then the write would fail and an error would be returned by the HDFS write operation. The operation is not considered completd until all of the replicas have been successfully written:

Here are specific details about HDFS high availability. TL;DR the last block is verified across **all** replicas before the overall write operation were considered completed. It is also not sufficient to just "fail". Instead automatic failover occurs consisting of finding a different datanode and writing the failed block(s) to it/them.

Details on block replica failure **detection**:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/02/understanding-hdfs-recovery-processes-part-1/

> If the last block of the file being written is not propagated to all
>   DataNodes in the pipeline, then the amount of data written to
>   different nodes may be different when lease recovery happens. Before
>   lease recovery causes the file to be closed, it’s necessary to ensure
>   that all replicas of the last block have the same length; this process
>   is known as block recovery. Block recovery is only triggered during
>   the lease recovery process, and lease recovery only triggers block
>   recovery on the last block of a file if that block is not in COMPLETE
>   state (defined in later section).

Details on block failure **recovery**:

> During write pipeline operations, some DataNodes in the pipeline may
>   fail. When this happens, the underlying write operations can’t just
>   fail. Instead, HDFS will try to recover from the error to allow the
>   pipeline to keep going and the client to continue to write to the
>   file. The mechanism to recover from the pipeline error is called
>   pipeline recovery.

I have experienced datanode / block write failures scores of times.  But have rarely  experienced that successful writes were "not really". And those rare occurrences were AFAICR due to corruption on the physical disks.

Comment: So increasing the replication factor means having slower writes? For a non HA cluster, could you point me at any specific documentation stating that ALL replicas need to ack ALL blocks before a write is considered successful? Your first block mentions packets and not replicas. Thanks!